# What is this part of the chart called in Vega-Lite?

Tags: data-visualization, vega-lite, vega

I'm trying to get rid of the right side of the box of a chart in Vega-Lite. I assume I can just set the color to white once I figure out what it's called. It's not the domain or the grid, what is it? For bonus points, what do I need to do to make it go away? Thanks.

[image: Picture of the chart with a part in question circled in red]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line which you have highlighted is called `stroke`, you will find it in `view` config as it is a part of your chart view and provide the value as white or transparent.

Refer the below snippet or [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AHE2bMoLgByCAAIImNlADWlnJqhxLbUuss6EcSopUkTBRUUAZ1QTRA4M5bBwhKKAhiEABfJUx1JFkIADM2dQQ0AG1QXJpBTDh1KOUghgRKCABPBCY2QQBebrN9AHk+-TM0gF0lZHV7KOFZOACoOXKyNFBiGjgAdxWQG3U2ezn0TOyIHCR1OFlMNPSQS4XlGlll0JAAD23yuEFlWqC5jLNHCHEBVBA4ApISJKJBvGgQbZkTS-VC5KEQOCpW7NT7rH5RZw0VwBTBAkEARwY2R0wR0pACsPh22UbGQTzQaMEGKxWKAA) reference:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Google's stock price over time.",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"}],
  "mark": "line",
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": "transparent"}},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal", "axis": {"grid": false}},
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative", "axis": {"domain": false}}
  }
}
```